# Getting the proper event.data from onWrite in Cloud Functions with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I feel like I'm just missing something silly here because all the examples including codelab show that accessing the event data is straightforward. But I can't get it to work.

I have a straightforward chat/conversation structure that looks like: 
    `conversations/uniqueconversationId/uniquemessageId/`
and inside the unique message I store text, user, etc. Every time a new message is posted in the app, I push a new message to the conversation.

In Cloud Functions, I want to know when a new message is posted and send a notification. This is almost 100% the same as the codelab example.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/conversations/{conversationId}').onWrite(event => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  // Only send a notification when a new message has been created.
  if (snapshot.previous.val()) {
    return;
  }

  console.log(snapshot);
  ...
```

All the examples show accessing the snapshot value is as simple as

```
const text = snapshot.val().text;
```

But that doesn't work for me.  When I attempt to access it, it says it is undefined. When I keep the check of snapshot.previous.val() which I pulled straight from codelab, it just returns, even though I'm posting a new message.  (And even if I take this out so I can log the snapshot, it still doesn't work.)

When I look in the console, the DeltaSnapshot is huge and contains all the message objects in the conversation.  I cannot directly access the new message values as expected.

Here is the chunk of code that writes to the DB (this is from React, BTW). This write works perfectly.

```
var messageData = {
    user: {
       _id: user.uid,
        name: user.fullName
    },
    text: messageText,
    createdAt:firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
    sentToUser: conversation.recipientUid
};


this.getRef().child('conversations').child(conversation.conversationId).push(messageData)
```

Here is the JSON for an example message:

```
{
    "-Km9qFcNClX3uQXX51D1" : {
      "createdAt" : 1496978098834,
      "text" : "Test message sent",
      "user" : {
        "_id" : "cKFnsNkYSyNXm5duUy",
        "name" : "Test User"
      }
    }
}
```

Ideally, based on the examples I would expect to be able to just use snapshot.val().text and get "Test message sent."

Any direction you can point me in will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your post to include the statement that writes the new message to the database.

Comment: Just updated to include it @BobSnyder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're triggering on writes one level too high.  You want writes to the message ID:

```
functions.database.ref('/conversations/{conversationId}/{messageId}').onWrite(...)
```

Then the snapshot will be for the `messageData` under `messageId` and not the list of all the messages in the conversation.

Comment: Ugh, I swear I tried that.  Thank you Bob for this quick response.  Works perfectly.